# I got this sitting in my garage for a few years now I was just trying to clean some stuff out trying to figure out what they're worth

Tags: bmx

I had the serial number and UPC I'm going to attach a photo as well.

[image]

If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it if it's a decent bike I can just give it to my son after I fix it up a little bit.

Comment: Have you tried the URL on the label?

Comment: http://davemirra.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't give valuations here.

Comment: Read [this](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question/1338#1338) if you want a shot at an answer. No one can help you without more detail and at least a decent picture in your question. Valuations are off topic.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, its a BMX made by Mirra Bikes, which is now found at http://davemirra.com/  The founder Dave Mirra passed away in 2016 and the site appears to be somewhat dormant.

> Beginning in late spring of 2017 the Mirraco brand will be retired.

[image]

As for your questions - any bike is better than no bike.  Fix it up for/with your son, let him ride and enjoy it.  A used bike has relatively low value, they're tools, not assets.

In terms of quality it is a decent bike and is higher than the "BSO" walmart grade, based on the website.  Your son will enjoy riding it, and more so can be involved with the fixing-up process.

Valuations are off topic here because they're of limited use, only relevant in your local area, and are highly subjective.

Comment: "tools, not assets". nice perspective :)